# Node.js port compatibility

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm starting an app in node.js, using socket.io and it's on the same server that runs apache, so port 80 is unavailable.  By default, it's using port 8080.  I read on [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software)'s site that port 843 is generally not blocked.

I understand this is also the port used for flash files.  Is there reason not to use port 843? or likewise, not to use port 8080?

Also, would the ideal solution be to use a different server and run on port 80?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there reason not to use port 843? or likewise, not to use port 8080?

Yes, I know some offices block all ports but the common ones (80, 21, 25, etc). If you're just testing node, playing around, or even during development, then it doesn't matter.

> Also, would the ideal solution be to use a different server and run on port 80?

Yep.

Answer (score 0):

Just run on port 8080, especially if you only use socket.io and not the complete node.js stack. Makes no difference if you ask me.

Comment: The reason to not run on 8080 is that some folk's networks, may block this port no?

Comment: This might be the case, but that's most the case at work. At that place they aren't allowed to visit your site anyway.